# How to run a firebase cloud function based on client platform?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-functions

I have an Ionic 5 web app that runs a cloud function `onUserCreate()` to create a stripe customer.

I want to deploy my ionic app to iOS and trigger a different firebase cloud function to interface with apple pay and not run the function to also create a customer with stripe.

How can I conditionally run this function based on the platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass a flag that indicates the source platform when you create the user

https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/platform